# WebService Client and List<JAXBElement<?>>

Tags: jaxb, cxf, webservice-client

When I try to generate a client from a wsdl document, I get a client that seems to have a lot of JAXBElement atributes, for instance

```
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> nameOrLinkingNameOrFamilyName;
```

I use soapUI to generate with apache cxf 2.3.3 as tool, also as config file the following:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
 xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
 xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
 <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
</jaxb:bindings>
```

As far as I saw this is related with the **choice** tags in the wsdl document.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `JAXBElement` will be generated for choice properties where multiple XML elements will correspond to the same Java class.  This is in order to preserve information about the element since this can not be derived from the type of the value.

**binding.xml**

The following JAXB schema bindings file will ensure that a choice property is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          version="2.1">
    <globalBindings choiceContentProperty="true"/>
</bindings>
```

---

**XML Schema That Will Produce `Object` Property**

In this version of the XML schema, all of the XML elements will correspond to a different Java class:

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="address" type="address"/>
    <xsd:element name="phone-number" type="phoneNumber"/>
    <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

Since the value of the choice property is sufficient to uniquely identify the element, the property does not contain a JAXBElement to preserve this information:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "address", type = Address.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "phone-number", type = PhoneNumber.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "note", type = String.class)
})
protected Object addressOrPhoneNumberOrNote;
```

---

**XML Schema That Will Produce `JAXBElement` Property**

Now we will modify the choice structure so that both the `note` and `email` methods will correspond to the `String` class.

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="address" type="address"/>
    <xsd:element name="phone-number" type="phoneNumber"/>
    <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

Since the value of the choice property is no longer sufficient to uniquely identify the element, the property must contain a JAXBElement to preserve this information:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "phone-number", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "email", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "address", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "note", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
protected JAXBElement<?> addressOrPhoneNumberOrNote;
```

---

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you tell me that **always** I'll get a JAXBElement<?> if I've got elements that correspond to the same Java class?

Comment: @Nicolas - This is true, and ensures that your XML document can be round tripped.  Without the JAXB element how would you differentiate which element should be used for the marshal (i.e. in my example would you wrap an instance of String in "email" or "note"?