# Generate JAX-WS Client using SoapUI without JAXBElement

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I'm generating a JAX-WS Client, using SoapUI. For some reason I couldn't understand yet, some attributes have been changed during the generation. For example, let's say I have an attribute address:

```
private String address;
```

After the generation, the address attribute changed to:

```
private JAXBElement<String> address;
```

Is there a way to avoid this change?

I found this question, but I'm not sure where to configure this binding.xml: [WebService Client and List<JAXBElement<?>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206405/webservice-client-and-listjaxbelement)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try addressing the [blog post mentioned](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html) on the answer marked as accepted for the question you refer?

Answer (score 1):

wsimport -keep -verbose http://service?wsdl -b format.xml

format.xml >

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```